# Help with understanding gauge transformation within PPN formalism

Tags: general-relativity

I am trying to learn PPN formalism (for testing modified gravity). As practice, I am trying to work through some papers. In order to test gravity against observation:

1. After we derive the equation(s) of motion from varying the action, is the next step to insert the weak field approximation for the metric ($g_{\mu\nu}\approx\eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}$), insert the corresponding approximations for the Ricci Tensor and Ricci Scalar, and perturb any fields (if necessary) about their central value (by that I mean approximate a scalar field $\Phi$ as $\Phi\approx \Phi_o + \varphi$ (with $\Phi_o$ a constant and $\varphi$ a small perturbation away from $\Phi_o$)?
2. After doing this, do we then drop any terms 2nd order and higher in small quantities.
3. When we choose a gauge, do we treat that gauge choice as another term to plug into our equation(s) of motion to further cancel out some terms (as long as we are not violating $\tilde{h}_{\mu\nu}=h_{\mu\nu} + \partial_\mu \xi_\nu + \partial_\nu \xi_\mu$)?

For practice, I am trying to work through [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.3401) paper. I arrived at Eq.(12) by plugging Eq. (10) and (11) into Eq. (9) and dropping all terms higher than first order in $h_{\mu\nu}$ and $\varphi$. However, in attempting to arrive at Eq. (13) I plugged in the same terms as above (plug in $\Phi\approx \Phi_o + \varphi$ and $g_{\mu\nu}\approx\eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}$) and I also inserted $\frac{1}{\Phi_o}\partial_\nu\varphi=\partial_\sigma h^\sigma _\nu - \frac{1}{2}\partial_\nu h$. However, after dropping terms higher than 2nd order in perturbations, I find 
\begin{equation}
\partial_\mu\partial_\nu\varphi - \frac{1}{2}\eta_{\mu\nu}\partial_\alpha\partial^\alpha \varphi-\frac{\Phi_o}{2}\left[ \Box\left( h_{\mu\nu}-\eta_{\mu\nu}\frac{h}{2}\right)\right]=8\pi g T_{\mu\nu} + \partial_\mu\partial_\nu \varphi - \eta_{\mu\nu}\Box\varphi
\end{equation}
(the first two terms on the left hand side are not in Eq. (13) of the paper).

4. In practice, is a gauge transformation really anything more than "plug in $\frac{1}{\Phi_o}\partial_\nu\varphi=\partial_\sigma h^\sigma _\nu - \frac{1}{2}\partial_\nu h$" (or whatever gauge condition you choose to work with) to help simplify the equations of motion?

If it is relevant, my Einstein Tensor in the weak field limit is
\begin{equation}
G_{\mu\nu}=R_{\mu\nu} -\frac{1}{2}Rg_{\mu\nu} \approx \frac{1}{2}\left[ \partial_\sigma\partial_\nu h^\sigma_\mu + \partial_\sigma\partial_\mu h^\sigma_\nu - \Box h_{\mu\nu} -\partial_\mu\partial_\nu h -\eta_{\mu\nu}\partial_\alpha\partial_\beta h^{\alpha\beta} + \eta_{\mu\nu} \Box h \right]
\end{equation}

(I don't intend on this being a 'check my work' type question, but I'm also trying to learn PPN via practice problems, and the fact that the extra terms still remain suggest that there is something I am not doing and/or don't understand. I checked my math multiple times.)