# Learning resources for the PPN formalism

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, perturbation-theory

I'm trying to learn more about the PPN formalism, and I was hoping to find some papers that show how the various parameters are calculated. Basically, I want to go through the usual calculations of finding the metric and identifying the various PPN parameters. I'm quite new to considering perturbations of the metric, so I'm looking for a paper or resource with a lot of calculations and intermediate steps.

I have the text *[Theory and experiment in gravitational physics](https://www.amazon.ca/Experiment-Gravitational-Physics-Clifford-1993-03-26/dp/B01A0BYJ8W?SubscriptionId=AKIAILSHYYTFIVPWUY6Q&tag=duc12-20&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B01A0BYJ8W)*, by Clifford M. Will. It's helpful in that it provides nice tables summarizing the parameters, but it does not give a lot of calculations (at least, for the part that I'm looking for). In particular, I'm looking for a resource that has the derivation of the results of Sections 5.2 and 5.3 of Will.

Does anyone know of such a source? I've seen related questions about the PPN formalism on this site, such as [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/381262/), but they have not received much of a response.

Comment: *Gravity* by Poisson & Will, chapters 6-8, give you what you want for Einstein gravity. For other theories you have to redo the derivation case by case.

Comment: *Basically, I want to go through the usual calculations of finding the metric and identifying the various PPN parameters.* This sounds not quite right. PPN can describe things that are not possible in GR or net describable by a metric. Can you give us a sample of a calculation you'd like to do?

Comment: BTW, if you're really referring to a book from 1993, be aware that it predates dark energy, LIGO's results, and imaging of black hole event horizons. See Will, arxiv.org/abs/1403.7377 instead.

Comment: @BenCrowell Yes, I have checked the arXiv version of the document as well. In terms of metric that I'm looking to get in GR, Equation 5.28 of the book says that $g_{00} = -1 + 2U - 2U^2 + 4 \Phi_1 + 4 \Phi_2 + 2\Phi_3 + 6 \Phi_4$ and so on for the metric, which we can then read off the PPN parameters. In terms of calculations I'd like to do, I'm in the midst of trying to calculate $R_{00}$, $R_{0j}$, and $R_{ij}$ to the correct order in the perturbation $h_{ab}$ (I'm using indices $a,b$ like we would with $\mu, \nu$).

Comment: @Void Thanks for the reference, I will check it out. I'm only looking for the GR case in order to see how the derivation is done. I can compute the others after.